# Django Password_reset Email settings

Tags: python, django

I'm learning the Django and doing a project now , in the tutorial it used the django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend to test the function , now I want to use my real email account to test the function . But after the setting , the smtp server always say the authorization problem (password 100% right)

```
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (553, b'Mail from must equal authorized user', 'webmaster@localhost')
```

Hope someone can give me the suggestion , thanks.

What I've done: complete the parameters in setting.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp server address here'
EMAIL_PORT = 25  
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'the sender email here'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password here'
EMAIL_FROM = 'Admin'
```

So I want to ask , besides these setting , is there any other setting I need to do ? 
I.E. for the real email account , shall I write the "send email" function by myself again....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove EMAIL_FROM smpt try to send mail from EMAIL_FROM and there nothing right , mostly EMAIL_FROM us for multiple email use in on project otherwise you can use your authenticate email in EMAIL_FORM

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp server address here'
EMAIL_PORT = 25  
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'the sender email here'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password here'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'same as EMAIL_HOST_USER'
```

Comment: Sorry, I've test it without"email from", it's same...is there any other setting for the email sending function , for example to write the sending function customized。？？

Comment: try to EMAIL_HOST_USER and replace EMAIL_FORM to DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL as there use same email

Comment: It works , thanks so much , the problem came from DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL , I set up it as your suggestion and the email function is fine now , have a good day to you!