# Django: SMTPRecipientsRefused for EmailBackend, but not smtplib

Tags: django

I set up Django's password recovery process, using the following settings in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.someserver.com' # mail service smtp
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'someone@fakeserver.com' # email id
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my password' #password
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

Elsewhere in my application, I use `smtplib` to send emails without any problem using the same server settings.

However, when I test the password recovery process, it fails with the following error: `SMTPRecipientsRefused 451 Temporary local problem - please try later`

I tried several server settings without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

The SMTPRecipientsRefused (451) error comes up because the server rejects the email.  What makes this difficult to solve is that the error does not really tell you precisely what went wrong.

I eventually found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937811/django-password-reset-email-settings) on StackOverflow and saw that I was missing one setting namely `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`.  My final working setup looks as follows:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.fakeserver.com' # mail service smtp
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'someone@fakeserver.com' # email id
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my password' #password
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'someone@fakeserver.com'
```

Note that the `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` value must be the same as the `EMAIL_HOST_USER` value.